# Fetch rows only from specific date in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch rows only from specific date (like today, yesterday or 2 days ago) in mySQL. I have a column named "date" in my rows. (which includes dates like 1365053426).

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from track WHERE `date` >= CURRENT_DATE
  AND `date`  < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

I have tried this query, but it returns "0". What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using `BETWEEN`?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount
FROM   Track
WHERE  Date BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL -2 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` is an additional knowledge for me.. How does this work :) ?

Comment: @Kaii it basically adds 1 day from the current date `:)` which is the same as `DATE_ADD`

Comment: @Kaii [MySQL DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: add or subtract? cause if it will be add that will suppose to be for tommorow right? like e.g. `BETWEEN April 4,2013 AND (April 4,2013 + INTERVAL 1 DAY)= April 5,2013` do i copy the logic :)

Comment: @Kaii right. `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` will add one day `+ INTERVAL -1 DAY` will subtract one day

Comment: I am still getting 0. Do I have to change "date" row structure to DATE ?

Comment: try `WHERE  DATE(Date) BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL -2 DAY AND CURDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

How about using `datediff()` function?

```
SELECT count(*) as total from track WHERE datediff(now(),date)=interval day
```

*note: interval day could be declare from 0 -> up depends on what previous date you want to show*